# Gnuplot: Combinging clustered histogram and rowstacked histogram styles in one chart

Tags: gnuplot, bar-chart, histogram

Does gnuplot provide the function to merge the styles of having a clustered histogram (with e.g. 3 bars in one cluster) while applying the rowstacked style to the columns? I would like to indicate that a distinct portion of each column belongs to one set whereas the rest belongs to another. In addition, I would have 3 different groups of data plotted as bars and this set would be plotted in 5 clusters on the x-axis.

I would be glad about your answers. Since I have not found any information on that I ask you for suggestions how *histogram clustered*/*data histogram* and the style *histogram rowstacked* could be combined in one chart.

Comment: Question answered? Problem solved? If yes, please accept the solution (check mark on the answer). If not please clarify. Any kind of response would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

An example is provided in the final plot of the standard "histograms.dem" demo file in the gnuplot distribution and in the on-line demo collection:

```
http://gnuplot.info/demo_5.5/histograms.html
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure whether this is what the OP was asking. But without response of the OP it is difficult to say. This is several rowstacked histograms next to each other.  I wanted to plot something similar and was about asking the same question and hence found this question. But for me a **rowstacked AND clustered** histogram would have interlaced bars, i.e. all `1891-1900` bars next to each other, etc. Is this possible? I haven't found yet an out of the box solution. I know I could draw it "manually".

Comment: Maybe you could do something with `newhistogram at <+/-offset>` and thinner bars. But it's not yet clear to me how to do it in a loop without specifying each offset manually and how to suppress the multiple legends.